# Creating data frames from lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, list

I'm starting to use pandas, and I need to create a data frame with the following columns: file names, index, path, original index. I saw some examples where they use something like this:
   `lst = [[fileNm,indSW[0],path,[trueStart[0],trueEnd[0]]], [fileNm,indSW[0],path,[trueStart[1],trueEnd[1]]]]`
pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['FileName','indSW','path','indFR'])
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIQXa.png)
And I obtain this data frame. My problem is that I need to start with an empty list and use a for loop to add new rows. In the end, I want to generate a data frame with all the indices I have. However, I'm not sure how to do it. I should clarify that my algorithm searches for indices, so I don't have all the information initially

Something like this

```
ls = []
for a in range(10):
    ls[a] = [fileNm,indSW[0],path,[trueStart[0],trueEnd[0]] 
    ls[a+1] = [fileNm,indSW[0],path,[trueStart[1],trueEnd[1]]
```

where indSw is a nmpy array, fineNm and path are str, and [trueStart[1],trueEnd[1]] is a list.
So finally I need to obtain a list ls, with a len for example 10 row,4 columns to convert it to a data Frame.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What data are you starting with? A data frame, multiple lists? Can you add a sample of your data

Comment: Please provide a [mre], images are **not** reproducible.